# PCA figure formatting options in R--changing individual points to group means/SE

Tags: r, visualization, pca, vegan

I tried this question in stats.stackexchange and somebody suggested I try it over here, so here goes:

I've completed PCA analysis, in R with VEGAN package, of some ecological data on tree health. There are 80 trees total (so, 80 'sites') divided into four treatment categories. I've got the data plotted with color coded points--colors according to the treatment groups. Rather than plotting individual sites/trees on PCA biplot, I'd like to make something like a box-and-whisker plot that has four 'crosses' that show the centroid for each group and the SE in both PCA dimensions. I've seen figures like this in papers, but I can't seem to find an R script for plotting this way. Any suggestions? (I'd like to post an example image here of what I'm looking for, but the ones I can find are all paywalled, sorry).

I guess an alternative would be to just take the site scores and manually find the means and SE's and create my own plot, but I'd rather find a script for it, if possible.

The code I've been running is really straightforward:

```
p1<-princomp(scale(health, scale=T))
summary(p1)
scores(p1)
plot(p1)
loadings(p1)
biplot(p1, xlab = "PC 1 (38%)", ylab = "PC 2 (22%)",cex=0.6)
plot(p1$scores[,1],p1$scores[,2])
names(p1)

plot(p1$scores[,1],p1$scores[,2], type='n', xlab="PC I", ylab="PC II")
text(p1$scores[,1],p1$scores[,2] labels=Can$tree)
```

Comment: You do realise that `princomp()` isn't in **vegan**, yes? & nor is it even recommended to use it (`prcomp()` is preferred, but even that isn't in **vegan**).

Comment: Yes, sorry to be confusing--I'm just showing the code that I have been playing with this morning. Any suggestions for a better package/script for what I'm trying to do? Or, along same lines, a resource for the differences between princomp() and prcomp()? I understand the stats side of things, but my R knowledge is spotty and mostly consists of things I've been shown by other folks. I can find plenty of documentation to read about individual packages, but would love a good resource for 'big picture' stuff like when and why to use one script vs. another. Thanks for your time-sorry to waste it.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying; I have almost finished an answer using vegan functions.

Comment: As for `princomp` vs `prcomp`, the former uses an Eigen decomposition whilst the latter uses the singular value decomposition (SVD). The latter is generally more robust and also offers a solution when there are more variables/columns than samples/rows. The `rda()` function in **vegan** also uses the SVD to compute the PCA.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would probably start with `ordiellipse` and see if that suits your needs.

```
### Reproducible example
require("vegan")
data(varespec)
data(varechem)

pca <- rda(varespec, scale = TRUE)
grp <- with(varechem, cut(Baresoil, 4, labels = 1:4))
cols <- c("red","orange","blue","forestgreen")
scl <- 1 ## scaling

plot(pca, display = "sites", scaling = scl, type = "n")
points(pca, display = "sites", scaling = scl, col = cols[grp], pch = 16)
lev <- levels(grp)
for (i in seq_along(lev)) { ## draw ellipse per group
  ordiellipse(pca, display = "sites", kind = "se", scaling = scl,
              groups = grp, col = cols[i], show.groups = lev[i])
}
## centroids
scrs <- as.data.frame(scores(pca, display = "sites", scaling = scl, 
                             choices = 1:2))
cent <- do.call(rbind, lapply(split(scrs, grp), colMeans))
points(cent, col = cols, pch = 3, cex = 1.1)
```

This produces

[image]

You can remove the `points()` line from the code above to stop it drawing the actual samples, but I thought it instructive here in terms of understanding what `ordiellipse` is doing.

In the plot, the centroid is marked as the mean of the site scores on each axis *by* grouping `grp`. The ellipse is a continuous region that is (given the setting I chose in the `ordiellipse()` call) 1 standard error about this centroid. Your suggestion for error bars in each direction is a specific case of the ellipse drawn by `ordiellipse` --- if you were to compute the standard errors of the centroids, they should extend as far as the extremal points of the ellipse in the horizontal and vertical directions.

However, this would fail to take into account the *covariances* of the scores on the two axes. Note in the example below how in those ellipses that are oriented at angles to the axes, the standard error bars do not intersect with the ellipse at their extremal points. If you were to draw a box containing the the region defined by the error bars, it would *contain* the ellipse, but it gives a very different impression of the uncertainty in the centroid.

```
serrFun <- function(df) {
  apply(df, 2, function(x) sd(x) / sqrt(length(x)))
}
serr <- do.call(rbind, lapply(split(scrs, grp), serrFun))
for (i in seq_along(lev)) {
    arrows(cent[i, 1] - serr[i, 1], cent[i, 2],
           cent[i, 1] + serr[i, 1], cent[i, 2],
           col = cols[i], code = 3, angle = 90, length = 0.05)
    arrows(cent[i, 1], cent[i, 2] - serr[i, 2],
           cent[i, 1], cent[i, 2] + serr[i, 2], 
           col = cols[i], code = 3, angle = 90, length = 0.05)
}
```

[image]

Comment: That's great, thanks for the detailed response. I appreciate what you are saying about the ellipse better representing the covariance structure.